# Python pickly ListIndexOut of Range

Tags: python, pickle

want to create a python script which checks if a server on a server is up or not. Rather if a server is up or not I want to catch that result in a file. In the end if a server is down then I want to receive an email.

I use the tutorial https://linuxhint.com/python-server-monitoring-script/ to start creating the python file with the below result.

When I execute the python file I get the below error. I not really familiar with working classes. So I hope you can help me out here.

When execute the below code i get the error you see below. And only the first server is checked. Can you please help me ?

**PREVIOUS RESULT**

```
$ C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe c:/Users/.../Documents/git/CV%20Reader%20FastAPI/CheckServer.py
1
('MyServernamae1 is up. On Port 80 with plain', True, <built-in method now of type object at 0x00007FFB92A8B530>)
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/.../Documents/git/CV%20Reader%20FastAPI/CheckServer.py", line 84, in <module>
    print(server.history[-1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**CURRENT RESULT**
Based on the given solution of 'Kite' i update the code and get the following result. I get for some of the servers result and some are skipped.  I expect for every server a result.

```
AzureAD+....@ToolingDesktop MINGW64 ~/Documents/git/CV%20Reader%20FastAPI (master)
$ C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe c:/Users/.../Documents/git/CV%20Reader%20FastAPI/CheckServer.py
5
('185.104.29.80 is up. On Port 80 with plain', True, datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 17, 16, 9, 31, 955477))
3
('No Clue??: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it', False, datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 17, 16, 9, 31, 985540))
```

**Expected Result**

I expect for every server a result (good or bad)!

This is the result from the https://linuxhint.com/python-server-monitoring-script/ site. I expect from the a response if the server is up or not.

[image]

**CODE UPDATE (BASED ON GIVEN SOLUTION)**

```
  from os import system
import socket
import ssl
import pickle
from datetime import datetime, time
import subprocess
import platform

class Server():
    def __init__(self, name, port, connection, priority):
        self.name = name
        self.port = port
        self.connection = connection
        self.priority = priority

        self.history = []
        self.alert =  False

    def checkConnection(self):
        msg = ""
        succes = False
        now = datetime.now()

        try:
            if self.connection == "plain":
                socket.create_connection((self.name,self.port),timeout=10)
                msg = f"{self.name} is up. On Port {self.port} with {self.connection}"
                succes = True
                self.alert = False
            elif self.connection == "ssl":
                ssl.wrap_socket(socket.create_connection((self.name,self.port),timeout=10))
                msg = f"{self.name} is up. On Port {self.port} with {self.connection}"
                succes = True
                self.alert = False
            else:
                if self.ping():
                    msg = f"{self.name} Timout on Port {self.port} with {self.connection}"
                    succes = True
                    self.alert = False

        except socket.timeout:
            msg = f"{self.name} is Down. On Port {self.port}"
            succes = False
            alert = True

        except Exception as e:
            msg = f"No Clue??: {e}"

        if succes == False and self.alert == False:
            # Send Alert
            self.alert = True
            # email_alert(self.name,f"{msg}\n{now}","erik.hoeven@gmail.com")
        self.create_history(msg,succes,now)

    def ping(self):
        try:
            output = subprocess.check_output("ping - {} 1 {}".format('n' if platform.system.lower() == 'windowns' else 'c', self.name), shell = True, universal_newlines = True)
            if 'unreachable'  in output:
                return False

            else:
                return True

        except Exception:
            return False

    def create_history(self,msg,succes,now):
        history_max = 100
        self.history.append((msg,succes,now))

        while len(self.history) > history_max:
            self.history.pop(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        servers = pickle.load(open("servers.pickle","rb"))
    except:
        servers = [
            Server("185.104.29.80",80,"plain","high"),
            Server("34.91.11.178",5001,"plain","high"),
            Server("reddit.com",80,"plain","high"),
            Server("msn.com",80,"plain","high"),
            Server("smtp.gmail.com",465,"ssl","high")
        ]
    for server in servers:
        server.checkConnection()
        print(len(server.history))
        print(server.history[-1])

    pickle.dump(servers,open("servers.pickle","wb"))
```

Comment: Have you dumped server.history without [-1]? Because if it is empty, its going to throw an error. Consider putting `self.create_history(msg,succes,now)` inside of the `except socket.timeout` block inside of `checkConnection()`, otherwise I don't know why you even bother trying for that exception. For the "general" `except` block, you should also consider writing out history as well, but specify that it was not a timeout error. You should put an if statement before `server.history` to catch if there isn't any history, so you don't try to reference something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the comment "ShanerM13" i have update the question and the result. Also the expected result.  Can you please help me ?

Comment: You deleted the Servers class. kite's answer might be the way to go... I was just making general observations.

Comment: Thanks for the general Observation. I also looked at the answer of Kite. I think we are in the right direction now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your code, I thought you had followed the tutorial as is but missed few minute things like below.

Firstly, the loading from pickle is not done properly. As it is with try/except block, it doesn't throw any error and it is the **main** issue.

```
#this is wrong
servers.pickle.load(open("servers.pickle","rb"))
#it should be like below
servers = pickle.load(open("servers.pickle","rb"))
```

Secondly, if you want the output to have visible datetime

```
#this just says as some object
now = datetime.now
#this gives the proper output
now = datetime.now()
```

Thirdly, why did you combine the email alert logic with other `if/elif` blocks only in `try` block. It should be added at the end of `try/except` blocks. (Logical issue)

Fourthly, This is what makes the `list index out of range` issue. In the `checkConnection()` last `except` block just says `pass`, which is very bad and if anything hits there, nothing is added in history too. So, I added the `self.create_history()` call as common for all `try/except` blocks and updated the last `except` to catch the other exceptions like `Connection refused`, `Temporary failure in name resolution` etc., instead of just `pass` and this adds something or the other in the `history`.

Please find my updated code below.

```
from os import system
import socket
import ssl
import pickle
from datetime import datetime, time
import subprocess
import platform

class Server():
    def __init__(self, name, port, connection, priority):
        self.name = name
        self.port = port
        self.connection = connection
        self.priority = priority

        self.history = []
        self.alert =  False

    def checkConnection(self):
        msg = ""
        succes = False
        now = datetime.now()

        try:
            if self.connection == "plain":
                socket.create_connection((self.name,self.port),timeout=10)
                msg = f"{self.name} is up. On Port {self.port} with {self.connection}"
                succes = True
                self.alert = False
            elif self.connection == "ssl":
                ssl.wrap_socket(socket.create_connection((self.name,self.port),timeout=10))
                msg = f"{self.name} is up. On Port {self.port} with {self.connection}"
                succes = True
                self.alert = False
            else:
                if self.ping():
                    msg = f"{self.name} Timout on Port {self.port} with {self.connection}"
                    succes = True
                    self.alert = False

        except socket.timeout:
            msg = f"{self.name} is Down. On Port {self.port}"
            succes = False
            alert = True

        except Exception as e:
            msg = f"No Clue??: {e}"

        if succes == False and self.alert == False:
            # Send Alert
            self.alert = True
            # email_alert(self.name,f"{msg}\n{now}","erik.hoeven@gmail.com")
        self.create_history(msg,succes,now)

    def ping(self):
        try:
            output = subprocess.check_output("ping - {} 1 {}".format('n' if platform.system.lower() == 'windowns' else 'c', self.name), shell = True, universal_newlines = True)
            if 'unreachable'  in output:
                return False

            else:
                return True

        except Exception:
            return False

    def create_history(self,msg,succes,now):
        history_max = 100
        self.history.append((msg,succes,now))

        while len(self.history) > history_max:
            self.history.pop(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        servers = pickle.load(open("servers.pickle","rb"))
    except:
        servers = [
            Server("185.104.29.80",80,"plain","high"),
            Server("34.91.11.178",5001,"plain","high"),
            Server("reddit.com",80,"plain","high"),
            Server("msn.com",80,"plain","high"),
            Server("smtp.gmail.com",465,"ssl","high")
        ]
    for server in servers:
        server.checkConnection()
        print(len(server.history))
        print(server.history[-1])

    pickle.dump(servers,open("servers.pickle","wb"))
```

After fixing these above issues, you will have the output like below:

```
1
('185.104.29.80 is up. On Port 80 with plain', True, datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 17, 15, 3, 47, 153334))
1
('No Clue??: [Errno 111] Connection refused', False, datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 17, 15, 3, 47, 425893))
1
('reddit.com is up. On Port 80 with plain', True, datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 17, 15, 3, 51, 216740))
1
('msn.com is up. On Port 80 with plain', True, datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 17, 15, 3, 51, 342316))
1
('smtp.gmail.com is up. On Port 465 with ssl', True, datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 17, 15, 3, 51, 670267))
```

Comment: Hi Kite, thanks for giving the solution. After changing the code as you sugested (i change the question with you sugestion). I still get empty response.  Maby is missed something!

Comment: @Erikhoeven, Did you forgot to uncomment this line `# print(server.history[-1])` ? As this is the print statement which prints the last entry in history.

Comment: Also, In `checkConnection()` last `except` block just says `pass` not reporting any error.  If anything hits there, history doesn't contain anything about it.

Comment: I had updated my answer with these issues mentioned in the comments;

Comment: Hi Kite, thanks for the fast response. I think i am almost there!  I get now for some servers a response. I expect for every server a response (as i also explained in the question). Manny thanks again.

Comment: I get only a respons for the adres 185.... adres

Comment: @Erikhoeven Did you remove the `servers.pickle` file and re-ran the above code ? Why I'm asking this is because if `servers.pickle` has only 1 entry then it will check the connection for only that entry.